# How to reset the value of an inputText to the original value on rowUnselectCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need your help in resetting the value in an inputText to its original value which is being retrieved on the page load once the checkbox of the row is unticked. In this case, I am having a dataTable and once the user clicks on the checkbox in the row, the inputText will be enabled and editable. I would like to do undo to the added text in the inputText if the user unticked the checkbox. In the current case, if the user unticked the row, then the added characters will remain in the inputText.

Here is the code for the dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testController.employeeList}" id="Employee" var="emp"
                             selection="#{testController.selectedEmployees}" rowKey="#{emp.id}" emptyMessage="No Employees found.">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{testController.EnableInputText}" update="Employee"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{testController.onRowUnselect}" update="Employee"/>
                    <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column/>
                            <p:column headerText="ID"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Name"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Remarks"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Delete"/>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remarks">
                        <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}" disabled="#{emp.disable}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

And the code in the backing bean:

```
private List<Employee> employeeList;

private List<Employee> selectedEmployees;

public void EnableInputText(SelectEvent event) {
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedEmployees.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < employeeList.size(); j++) {
            if (selectedEmployees.get(i).getId().equals(employeeList.get(j).getId())) {
                employeeList.get(j).setDisable(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent unselectEvent) {
    Employee emp = (Employee)unselectEvent.getObject();

    for (Employee e : employeeList) {
        if (emp.getId().equals(e.getId())) {
            e.setDisable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose the value in the inputText is Test and the user ticked the checkbox in the row and editted it to Test555 then on the untick of the checkbox, the inputText value should return back to Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be easy.

You just need to use another variable `oldRemarks`. During the initialization of the employee list set the oldRemarks=remarks.

```
public Employee(Integer id,String name,String remarks,Boolean disabled){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.oldRemarks = remarks;
    }
```

And in your UnselectEvent

```
public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent unselectEvent){
    Employee emp = (Employee)unselectEvent.getObject();

    for (Employee e : employeeList) {
        if (emp.getId().equals(e.getId())) {
            e.setDisabled(true);
            e.setRemarks(e.getOldRemarks());
        }
    }
}
```